# How to create this UI in windows phone to show image and Text in continuos text wrapping?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to create this kind of UI in Windows phone, which can be done with flowdocument in WPF?
Is there any flowdocument control availble in Windows Phone and is there any other way?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232203/wpf-layout-for-autosize-textblock-and-icon-floating-on-the-right-how, I think that it's the same question

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution for this problem. By measuring the text you can split the text manually to two parts>

```
<Grid Width="400">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="WrapContent" Width="200" Height="192" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="RightTextBlock" Width="200" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="BottomTextBlock" Width="400" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    RightTextBlock.Text = words[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        string word = words[i];
        string previousText = RightTextBlock.Text;
        RightTextBlock.Text += " " + word;
        if (RightTextBlock.ActualHeight > WrapContent.ActualHeight)
        {
            RightTextBlock.Text = previousText;
            BottomTextBlock.Text += String.Join(" ", words.Skip(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```